# How to control the z-index on this specific suggestion box

Tags: css

I'm trying to make this suggestion box be on top.
[image: picture of dior search]
I can't get the z-index to work properly. Any suggestions on how to edit the CSS to make it overlap the next content block?

Site URL: https://shop.cph.dk/thejourneyison

Comment: `z-index: #`, it needs `position` to be set to something other than `static`. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.class {
    position:absolute
          *or*
    position:relative
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```